# Get the sum of an attribute in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal

I have 2 models, `Agent` and `Currency` with the following relationship.

```
Agent has_many :currencies

Currency belongs_to :agent
```

I have the following code.

```
agent = Agent.find(1)

agentcurrs = agent.currencies
```

`Currency` has an attribute called 'val'.

I want the sum of 'val' for the `agentcurrs` recordset so I'm doing the following:

```
totalval = agentcurrs.sum('val')
```

A `BigDecimal` is being returned rather than the value.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Rails 2.3.8 and Ruby 1.8.

Comment: A BigDecimal is a value, what's the problem? Where are you not able to use the returned value?

Comment: Equally confused.  BigDecimal is a number.

Comment: I'm guessing you're testing this in a console, and are confused at seeing the result being printed to screen in the form of #<BigDecimal:1055eac08,'0.165645747E1',12(20)>. This is just the way that BigDecimals are inspected though. If you just want to see a number, you can do a puts instead: puts totalval.

Comment: @Dogbert @d11wtq Yes I was confused by the way the BigDecimal is shown in the console.  Both Float and Integer don't come up looking like that, just the plain old value.  @Frankie You guessed right the way the BigDecimal is shown in the console was the problem.  Thanks everyone for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Do what Frankie suggests, or call object_result.to_i.